# (Bt)^2 it is a martingale?

Tags: probability, martingales

Well i think no, because the expected value is t

E[(Bt)^2)=t, so it´s not constant, change with the time.

Am I right?

Propz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. If it were a martingale, the expectation would be $0$. Not sure if you're interested, but $B_t^2 - t$ is a martingale.

Comment: Ty! And exp(a*Bt-(a^2t/t)) it´s a martingale?
After some calculations, I get the next expected value:
exp(aBs-0.5a^(2)*s). So, it´s not a martingale too, right?

Comment: @Zacarias, no $\exp(aB_t - a^2\frac{t}{2})$ is a martingale. I think your calculation was **conditional** expectation.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it was conditional expectation. Ty dude! I am yet a noob.